# How to install Gnome 3 in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Tags: 10.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome)

Someone can to explain how to install gnome3-session in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Thanks!!!
Sorry to my English :-)

Comment: This question may not be a duplicate, because this specifically asks about 10.04. Unfortunately running the latest GNOME 3 builds in older Ubuntu versions may be difficult (seeing as it's hard enough running them in new versions).

Comment: I'm leaving this separate from the other question because it is version specific and the other thread's answers only cater to 11.04