# Is there an up-to-date gnome-shell PPA?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install the latest GNOME 3 build?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-to-install-the-latest-gnome-3-build)

Is there an up to date PPA of gnome-shell? I have a number of issues building it, and I'd prefer not to use an old version.

Answer (score 0):

It only has packages for Ubuntu 11.04, but [Rico Tzschichholz's Testing PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing) has recent gnome-shell builds.