# Will I be able to switch to Gnome-Shell in 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I'm a bit confused about whether or not Gnome-shell is a new distribution or just a desktop environment? Will shell be available to install and use instead of Unity?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### About gnome-shell

`gnome-shell` is just a shell and not a new distribution or desktop environment.

The Desktop Environment is Gnome and `gnome-shell` the shell comes with version3 of Gnome Desktop Environment

Please don't confuse gnome-shell or unity with Window Manager too. Both of them are not window manager. For gnome-shell the WM is Mutter and for unity WM is Compiz.

### Availability in Natty

With respect to availability of gnome-shell in Ubuntu, it won't be in 11.04. It is present [in a PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them). There were some valid **technical** reasons for keeping it in a PPA. [This bug discusses the issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/690045) Quoting from it

```
Due to the state of the GNOME3 stack in natty, we won't be able to 
upgrade gnome-shell to 2.91.x. In addition, due to libraries that 
have already changed, (Bug #685225 and Bug #677382), gnome-shell 
is currently broken. We also have the xulrunner-2.0 transition to 
consider. Due to all this, we believe it best to remove gnome-shell 
from natty.
```

Also I found a [mail titled Status update on GNOME3 and natty](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-desktop/2011-January/002740.html) sent by Sebastian Bacher dated Jan 20th 2011. It contains a lot of status updates. Go through it.

Instructions for trying GNOME3 (and GNOME Shell) are at this question:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Comment: For unity 2d the WM is Metacity, to complete your list

Comment: Yeah true. Thanks Compiz is 3D compositing manager. Previously Compiz only worked with 3D hardware but as of now it can use AIGLX.

Comment: Just an update. I heard Unity 2D would be migrated to Compiz (with no effects)

Comment: How is working gnome-shell with 11.04 at this point? Is it reliable?

Comment: The PPA has gnome-shell, but there is guarantee still. I heard most of the issues have now been fixed, but as usual no guarantee