# Will 11.04 support Gnome SHELL?

Tags: gnome, 11.04, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will I be able to switch to Gnome-Shell in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29620/will-i-be-able-to-switch-to-gnome-shell-in-11-04)

I was just wondering if the GNOME SHELL (Not Gnome 3 and GTK3) will be in the ubuntu repos in 11.04. I know it is in the repositories for 10.10, but it quite outdated. I like Unity and Gnome Shell, and have spent time using both, but I just went back to 10.10 from 11.04 as Unity and compiz keep crashing on alpha 3. I was just wondering if the Shell would be in the 11.04 repositories for release?

Comment: If it is not in the main repository somebody will build a PPA and might I add the unity is not quite complete yet and will probably be better with stability when it is deemed complete.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not. Unity is there to replace Gnome shell.

That doesn't mean that someone will not provide a ppa to install Gnome shell, though.