# will I be able to run Gnome-shell on Ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will I be able to switch to Gnome-Shell in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29620/will-i-be-able-to-switch-to-gnome-shell-in-11-04)

Will gnome-shell have full support on ubuntu 11.04? Will I be able to choose to run Gnome-shell as my desktop instead of Unity and get the full gnome-shell experience--the same desktop capabilities as a default install of the Fedora distro would provide, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is reasonable to believe that the Gnome-shell will be available in the official repository of the Ubuntu 11.04 since it is on 10.10 and 10.04.
Look at [Developers Talk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/01/ubuntu-developers-talk-unity-and-why-its-going-to-rock-in-natty-video/).

Comment: That's old, there's no gnome-shell in the repositories for 11.04, here's the instructions how: http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3

Comment: Will Unity use version 3 of Gnome Desktop Environment? What Desktop Environment will Unity use? My understanding is that Gnome-shell is a shell that can be used for the Gnome (version 3) Desktop Environment.

Comment: Currently Unity at Natty is using version 2.32.1.