# Is there a Gnome3 stable PPA?

Tags: 11.04, ppa, gnome

Is there a Gnome3 stable PPA yet? Or will it become available in the Natty repositories later this month?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GNOME3 won't be in 11.04. There is a PPA available, but it still has some issues that will be ironed out over time.

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)
- [Will I be able to switch to Gnome-Shell in 11.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29620/will-i-be-able-to-switch-to-gnome-shell-in-11-04)

Comment: Ok ;) I understand!