# GNOME 3  from the software center is slow and buggy

Tags: 10.10, gnome

When I install gnome 3 from ubuntu software centre, I feel it is too slow and the windows decorations are not clear.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check which version of GNOME3 you have installed?
The version you get from the Software Center is probably more than a year old.

If you cannot find the version in the Software Centre, run instead

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell
```

which will indicate which version was installed.

I think a good option is to compile GNOME Shell. May sound daunting, but it's quite easy (no skills required) if you follow the instructions at:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)
- http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/

Answer (score 0):

The most probably cause is that you're using proprietary drivers. Both nvidia and AMD users have problem(e. g. me :] ). If you want to try GNOME Shell, try to run it using opensource drivers - nouveau(for Nvidia) or radeon(for AMD).  Intel should work flawlessly out of the box :)