# Will Gnome 3 replace my current Gnome session? Or will I be able to use both?

Tags: 10.04, gnome

I saw that there's a PPA for Gnome 3.
I also noticed that it installs as another package. So my question is...

If I install the Gnome 3 package, will I be able to still use my current Gnome? Or will I be able to use only Gnome 3?

Thanks for any/all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will replace your current session. Rolling back is problematic, please see the warnings here:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

(Also I notice you tagged your question with [10.04](/questions/tagged/10.04), the PPA won't work with that anyway.)

Comment: It really won't work with 10.04? I had read somewhere it would. Okay, guess that solves the issue for me for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also install the gnome-shell without touching your system:

[installation instructions for gnome-shell](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-gnome-shell-from-git-in-ubuntu.html)

I tried it yesterday with 10.10 and it works fine.