# How to install Gnome 3 without breaking Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome

I tried installing gnome 3 [from the ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3), but it broke Unity and I had to reinstall Natty from scratch.

Does anyone know if there is a way to install Gnome 3 without breaking Unity?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is currently no easy way to do this, GNOME 3 requires a major transition to the GTK+ stack (from 2 to 3) that has not been done in Ubuntu yet.

This is a goal for 11.10, but currently I'm afraid trying GNOME3 on Ubuntu is more of a one-way upgrade.

Comment: I was going to mention the same thing since i read somwhere Jorge Castro mention that Gnome 3 could not be installed while using Unity since both would break each other and then he comes and posts here hehe. +1

Comment: Is this answer still up to date? I'd like to repost the question but I fear the communities down votes ;D

Answer (score 7):

I used the instructions at the attached link to install Gnome Shell on 11.04 without breaking Unity.

> "By compiling Gnome Shell using the instructions in this post, all the packages the Gnome >Shell script will download and compile will not replace any existing libraries and it >will install in your home folder, so you don't have to worry about breaking stuff on your >system (excluding here the build dependencies of course, which are usual packages from >the Ubuntu repositories and will install just like any other package)"
>
> http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/install-gnome-shell-from-git-in-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, Gnome-Shell is based on Gnome 3 which has a different ABI and Unity is based on Gnome 2, because of this you can't install Gnome-Shell without breaking Unity.

Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot will be based on Gnome 3, this way Gnome-Shell will not be a problem to install.

Comment: gnome3 installs fine on 11.10, `apt-get install gnome-shell` is all that's needed, and after a reboot you can select which shell you want to log into.

Answer (score 1):

I installed it from the ppa and it dosen't really "break" Unity, it just adds GNOME 3 interface, which overwrites the Gnome 2 interface, which is quite different. Except after, I decided I would like to use the Ambiance and Radiance themes again, So I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10.