# Will gnome3 installation affects unity?

Tags: unity, 11.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install gnome 3 without breaking Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34750/how-to-install-gnome-3-without-breaking-unity)

Gnome3 is out in the market and there has been a lot of talk about it. I like Unity interface very much. However, I was thinking to try out Gnome3 as well. But, wanted to be careful. I've already setup unity and I don't want to mess up. Is installing gnome3 will affect Unity desktop by chance ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, I was able to add the PPA, install and use GNOME 3, and then remove it effortlessly, without breaking my Unity setup.

I added the GNOME 3 PPA, installed all the required packages and libs, logged out and tried GNOME 3. Then I used this little neat utility called **ppapurge** (in the repos) to remove and revert all packages from the GNOME 3 PPA. It worked wonderfully. Just to reallly check it, I did a quick scan through Synaptic of all packages in the PPA, and none was installed.

It worked not only for me, but for others too. However, if you really praise your Unity setup, it's probably better not to touch anything. And anyway, the current GNOME3 experience in Ubuntu Natty is way below of what it should be, and I recommend you to try it using one of the live images made available on [gnome3.org](http://gnome3.org).

Comment: Thanks. "the current GNOME3 experience in Ubuntu Natty is way below of what it should be" - What are the things missing or not at expected level .

Answer (score 0):

Gnome 3 will break your unity installation.
There is still no possibility to get them both in one ubuntu-installation.