# Problems in Gnome-shell and GNOME3 in ubuntu 11.04?

Tags: 11.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome 3 ppa was unstable until April 28th, so is it ok now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37600/gnome-3-ppa-was-unstable-until-april-28th-so-is-it-ok-now)

How is GNOME3 reliability in Natty 11.04? 
Do you think production machines can be migrated to it or it's too early? I mean I'd like to move to it but I don't want to spend a lot of time fixing a broken gnome installation...

Comment: what are you using now?

Comment: currently using GNOME2 + metacity (w/o Compiz)

Comment: @Binarylife : actually I'm not asking about Unity/G3 compatibility problems... just trying to understand how G3 is working under natty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gnome3 (Gnome-shell) works perfectly well under natty. I did a Ubuntu-minimal installtion and started from scratch that way. This is the best way imho. Otherwise you get other, residual stuff from the Unity installtion. It's worth doing if anything to get practice with the terminal commands, and it's fun in to the bargain.

Gnome3.shell has a long way to go before its fully ready to be shipped as default. I know fedroa 15 has it but fedora is meant to be bleeding edge. There aren't enough utilites for it yet but it is perfectly stable to use. If anything I've found it more stable than Unity has been on natty.

Comment: But you still can't go back to using Unity if you install Gnome Shell, right?

Comment: in natty, it is the case that you can't go back once it's installed no. This should be changed for Oneirc though.

I bought a cheap hdd to try the gnome shell experience instead of borking my natty one.