# How safe is update to Gnome3?

Tags: upgrade, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome 3 ppa was unstable until April 28th, so is it ok now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37600/gnome-3-ppa-was-unstable-until-april-28th-so-is-it-ok-now)

How safe is update Natty with Gnome3 provided by this PPA? Are there any known issues which can cause serious trouble? I don't care about "look and feel" issues but I need to:

- Do NOT lose my data. Never, no way.
- Be able to run IDE, browser, music player, IM, evince etc... The "main" apps, basicaly those which are present in clean ubuntu installation.

Is it safe to update? If not, when is the stable version going to be released?

Comment: Which ppa are you referring to?

Comment: It's hard to find relevant information for "now". And I'm referring to this: https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3

Comment: The answer is same now as it was in the question I linked, wait until 11.10, the PPA you linked even says "This PPA is EXPERIMENTAL and MAY BREAK YOUR SYSTEM. There is no downgrade process."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade to Gnome 3 for Natty involves updating much of the GTK libraries - and as the forums (and AskUbuntu) have shown, some applications no longer work or had to be manually worked-around.

The core Gnome apps upgraded by the PPA does work fine - now - certainly didnt in the early days of the PPA. Thus the IDE, banshee, firefox etc works ok.

The PPA is a testing PPA.  If you are worried by data loss - backup with a full disk image.

Oneiric is less than two weeks away - my strong recommendation is wait until then.  When the upgrade is available, disk-image your system,  *ppa-purge* all PPAs and then upgrade.