# Can I run Gnome 3 in Classic Desktop and still switch to default Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

I am using Unity and am pretty stisfied. Anyway I want to give Gnome 3 a try within my working machine. Can I upgrade my system (Natty) so I have Gnome3 (+Shell) in the Classic Desktop mode and still switch back to a functional Unity default Natty Desktop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Gnome 3 without breaking Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34750/how-to-install-gnome-3-without-breaking-unity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Unity only works with Gnome 2 and both Gnome versions do not really reside side to side with each other.

Comment: your correct  unity doesn't play well with gnome 3 . We can only hope that 11.10 makes this possible

Comment: I think unity is going to be ported to Gnome 3.

Comment: I can confirm that Gnome 3 breaks Unity in Ubuntu 15.10 too. If you want to run both you will have to run one in a VM. I would suggest make a choice. Personally I have found the development in Gnome 3 is improving with every release and functionality is returning. FYI. I have installed Cinnamon next to Gnome 3 and they play nice.

Comment: AFAIK the underlying problem is that Unity has forks of the GNOME programs to remove the systemd dependencies (should no longer ne needed) and other things. The problem seems to be that the different versions do not work well next to each other. Mate and/or Cinnamon has forked the programs with a different name, so that they do not clash.