# Can I have both unity 2d and gnome 3 sessions available?

Tags: 11.04, unity, gnome

I don't mean i want to run both GUI'S  at the same time . I mean if I can install Gnome 3 and have unity-2D which I can change back and forth at any time by logging out and logging back in deciding what session GUI I want.

I am running ubuntu 11.04 with unity 2d on an acer aspire one netbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 uses Gnome 3 by default and yes, you can easily have both Unity, Unity 2D and Gnome Shell in it. 11.04, however, is based on Gnome 2 and cannot use Gnome Shell without fairly large changes to the system. I would wait until you're comfortable and upgrade to 11.10. Then you can just apt-get install gnome-shell. Unity2D really rocks in 11.10, btw. I know people who actually prefer it to Unity and it's actually understandable, though I prefer Unity myself. Gnome Shell is also very nice in 11.10. :)

I would not recommend using a PPA to get Gnome Shell on 11.04.

Comment: alright!! :) thancx for the info, now i dont have to go though so mucha trouble and i can relax, i was alreadu getyng the package by terminal and it failed to load so now i can sit back and relax :)
thanx Jo-Er;end Schinstad

and alsow thanx to fossfreedom :P you were both assets x) help apretiated

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to do this, GNOME 3 requires a major upgrade to the GTK+ software libraries i.e. moving from GTK+2 to GTK+ 3 which was not done for Ubuntu (Natty).

This is certainly possible for 11.10 since Oneiric uses much of the GTK+ 3 software libraries.

For Natty - installing GNOME3 via the PPA on Ubuntu is more of a one-way upgrade - quick search here or on Ubuntu Forums show numerous people having major issues trying to revert back to Unity/Unity-2D.

- Linked Question: [How to install Gnome 3 without breaking Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34750/how-to-install-gnome-3-without-breaking-unity)

Comment: ok well , ive thought a little and i have my backfaal now so, is there any ways to install gnome 3 in ubuntu natty? i am ruyng an nacer aspire one netbook and ive seen people that have gnome 3 on the same computer as mine and it works just fine but for some reason everytime i try to go into gnome 3 it fails to load and i still have unity 2d

Comment: That is really another question.  However I would advise you to have a closer look at the current oneiric beta if  you want gnome3.  The PPA for gnome 3 on natty can cause many breakage issues due to the extensive upgrade it involves.  For me the current oneiric beta is not bad - there are a few crashes, but its getting better everyday.