# How do I get Unity back after Gnome Shell install?

Tags: unity, gnome

I was running an up to date version of Ubuntu 11.04. For the purpose of a review, I decided to install Gnome Shell along side my Unity session. But after the process was completed, I can no longer log into the Unity session. Is there a way to remedy this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removal instructions are here:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

(Though I don't know how well it will work)