# After the removal of Ubuntu Classic in 11.10, will I be able to install it once again?

Tags: unity, gnome, window-manager, 11.10

After Ubuntu Classic is removed in 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot), will I be able to re-install it?

Comment: Probably not, since they are suppose to drop GNOME 2 for GNOME 3, so you would have to get rid of GNOME  3 related stuff to have the classic desktop.

Comment: That really bites  :-(

Comment: @Uri Herrera GNOME3 has a classic session it is used as fallback when gnome-shell is not available(http://www.webupd8.org/2011/03/classic-gnome-3-beta-2-video-no-shell.html) .

Comment: Thanks Alaukik, I will look into that. I've been wanting to try either Fedora, or OpenSUSE for a while now. I've heard that it's easier to set up on Fedora though.

Comment: @Alukik but still it's not GNOME 2 but 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You always will be able to open another session (in GDM) and customize it.

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Comment: Whew... that's a relief. Ubuntu Classic is nice, but the fact that I can no longer adjust graphical effects makes it very... choppy (for lack of a better word) on my computer. Thanks!

Comment: @Alan: Do you tried with Compiz Config Settings Manager? It should work with any session...

Comment: I most certainly will, that's the only other option I can think of. Hopefully it'll run better!

Comment: In this link there isnt about Ubuntu Classic

Answer (score 0):

Heres how to get to Ubuntu-Classic look [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic) using Gnome 3 couse GNOME 2 will not be available in 11.10 as the entire stack (including GTK) has been upgraded to 3.x. [Will I be able to run Gnome 2 in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54626/will-i-be-able-to-run-gnome-2-in-11-10)