# Ubuntu 11.10 Slow on Acer Aspire 5253

Tags: 11.10

My Acer Aspire 5253 is running slower than 11.04, after I activate ATI's propietary drivers, ¿any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would switch to Ubuntu Classic until bugs are fixed with graphics cards. I know that nVidia is the worst for that, this is the first ATI that I've seen. I would file a bug report.

Comment: ¿How do I switch to ubuntu classic?

Comment: @levhita The option's now called Ubuntu 2D, actually. You change your session at the login screen (see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21686/how-do-i-install-and-switch-to-the-unity-2d-desktop/64236#64236) for more information).

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 is also very slow on my computer and AMD athlon 64 3700+, 3gb ddr 400 ram and a nvidia 7900gto. Try installing the Gnome 3 shell and use that. It is alot faster on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong- Ubuntu 2D is Unity 2D without effects. By default 11.10 doesnt have Ubuntu classic.
11.10 still with Ubuntu-Classic installed from different PPA isnt looking as Classic but

also check my answer for what is faster for now https://askubuntu.com/questions/76997/which-is-better-staying-with-10-04-lts-until-12-04-comes-out-or-upgrading-to-11

And heres is problem solving to actually get IN ubuntu 11.10 back the Look of Gnome2 but with Gnome 3 modifying [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic) and u cant get "GNOME 2 will not be available in 11.10 as the entire stack (including GTK) has been upgraded to 3.x." from [Will I be able to run Gnome 2 in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54626/will-i-be-able-to-run-gnome-2-in-11-10)