# How to remove session entries from LightDM?

Tags: login, lightdm, menu

I recently added Cairo Dock to my GNOME Shell in 11.10. Cairo Dock is GREAT, but I'm left with one little problem that I'd like to fix: after installing Cairo Dock, LightDM includes two extraneous entries to non-working desktops.  (The entries to working desktops remain unaffected, so I guess I could just ignore the extraneous entries, but...)

So I'd like to remove/edit the extraneous entries in LightDM.  I've looked and looked for discussions on how to do so, but haven't had much luck.

Any suggestions on how to go about editing the login menu in 11.10?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The list of sessions is defined by the *.desktop* files in the folder `/usr/share/xsessions`

[image]

Lets remove *GNOME Classic*

In a terminal:

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
sudo mv gnome-classic.desktop gnome-classic.desktop.backup
```

This renames the *gnome-classic* desktop file

Logout - the new list of sessions will look like:

[image]

Comment: Is there a per-user equivalent for /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop?

Answer (score 23):

Your package maintainers will be proud of you if you do it as follows:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/xsessions/hidden
sudo dpkg-divert --rename \
      --divert /usr/share/xsessions/hidden/gnome-classic.desktop \
      --add /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop
```

What this does is to instruct the package manager to remember a new location for the file.  This has several advantages over the other answers:

- It guarantees a future package install/upgrade won't revert your change
- It works with other display managers (lxdm for example lists `.backup` entries)
- You can revert it easily if you change your mind with:

  `sudo dpkg-divert --rename --remove /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop`

Answer (score 12):

- Open terminal with `Ctrl-Alt-T`
- `cd /usr/share/xsessions`
- `ls` will show you, for example:

  ```
  awesome.desktop  gnome-shell.desktop  ubuntu.desktop
  gnome.desktop    ubuntu-2d.desktop
  ```
- Use `sudo rm lubuntu.desktop` (or whatever) to remove the ones you don't need any longer.
- Logout and you should see the changes -- if not, reboot and you will see them.

Comment: Thanks!  It also worked for my openbox environment that I removed.