# Managing the login screen's sessions list

Tags: login, session

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove session entries from LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

On Oneiric, I just installed a bunch of desktop environments / shells / windows managers by installing the `kubuntu-desktop`, `xubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop`, `e17` and `gnome-desktop` packages. Sometimes I enjoy a little variety, so I prefer to login to a random one each time I boot up. However, now the list of sessions I can choose from has close to 20 choices. I only want maybe five or six options, so most of them I will never use, e.g. Unity2D, or Xfce (I'd just use for the Xubuntu session). So I was wondering if there is a way to edit this list to only show the session I actually care about.

Comment: @fossfreedom: Yep, that looks like the same question. Got a good answer, too!