# How do I remove some sessions from the session list in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, session

When logging in to Xubuntu, I get a selection list of saved sessions, most of them is outdated old stuff.

I hit the delete button in a sportive manner. I tried a click to the left, and just a click to the right - no deletion possible.

I went through system menus and menu sections (and the system section of the menu).

Note: Not related: [How to remove session entries from LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm) or [Managing the login screen's sessions list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88097/managing-the-login-screens-sessions-list) which links to it - they handle session-classes like xubuntu vs. xfce, gnome, kde - not different xfce-sessions.

Note: I want to remove **some** sessions, not all of them. I don't want to start with the session-list deactivated. I have 5 entries and want to remove 3 of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Sagarchalise* brought me on the right track, but only half the way.

The place, where to look in Xfce is indeed

```
$HOME/.cache/sessions
```

I found a lot of files there, including some empty Thunar- files, xfwm4- files and, interesting for us, `xfce4-session-asux:0`, where `asux` is the name of my local machine, the hostname.

:0 reminds of the way, the XServer enumerates different instances, which I used rarely, but I used it, so I have a `xfce4-session-asux:1` file as well, and it is rather old, but different sessions aren't stored in different files, but in different sections inside the file.

Such a section looks like this:

```
[Session: 2010]
key1=value1
key2=value2
...
LastAccess=1315125649
```

So you can see the name ("2010" in this case) of the session, a bunch of key-value-pairs, and as last these pairs a LastAccess key. It stores the seconds since 1.1.1970 UTC. It's not short and easy to translate it to a human readable date with `date` or `bash arithmetic` (or tell me how in the comments). But at least the age in years is worth calculating:

```
echo $((1315125649/(365*24*60*60)))
41
```

So it is 41 years after 1.1.1970 (ignoring leap years and daylight saving time, and cutting the result to whole years) which is 2011. The other fields can be computed as well - I prefered to do it with `scala` by

```
scala> val d = new java.util.Date (1315125649*1000L)
d: java.util.Date = Sun Sep 04 10:40:49 CEST 2011
```

So I remove the whole section, and after relogin, this session is vanished from my list of sessions.

#### update:

I now know the much simpler solution for the date issue, simply put into the shell:

```
date -d @1315125649
So 4. Sep 10:40:49 CEST 2011
```

So this can be made into a simple script:

```
for f in  ~/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-* 
do
   la=$(sed -n -r 's/LastAccess=(.*)/\1/p' "$f")
   echo -e $(date -d @$la) "\t$f"
done 

Fr 9. Mär 07:17:13 CET 2018     /home/stefan/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-tux201t:0
Fr 9. Mär 07:16:03 CET 2018     /home/stefan/.cache/sessions/xfce4-session-tux201t:0.bak
```

Comment: exactly what I need

Comment: @gboffi: Thanks. Alarmed by your upvote, I suspect, I revisited this answer and extended it a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Go to `$HOME/.cache/sessions` and open the latest file with the name `xfce-session-yourdesktopname` in a text editor.

All your sessions are listed in the file by name in this format:

```
[Session: Default]
```

or

```
[Session:somename]
```

Select the entire set of lines from `[Session:somename]` to the next blank line (including the [Session:somename] line and delete them. Save the file.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK most of the display managers handle sessions from `.desktop` files present in `/usr/share/xsessions`. I guess renaming it to something else will remove session entries.

**E.g.**

```
cd /usr/share/xsessions
mv gnome.desktop gnome.desktop.backup
```

xfce caches its session in `$HOME/.cache/sessions` as well as has configurations in `$HOME/.config/xfce4-session`. You could try viewing those folders as well. I think xubuntu has folders with names `xubuntu` in place of `xfce` as it has its own session manager.

Comment: As I expected, only root has write access to `/usr/share/xsession` and its subfolders. gnome.desktop is of course completly off topic. `$HOME/.cache/sessions` seems the right thing: older and younger entries, `xfce4-session-*` and `xfwm4-*`-files are laying around. After renaming them and relogin (which might take some time) you might get the "accepted" flag, but the /usr/share part should really be removed. The `$HOME/.config/xfce4-session` directory only contains a 2 and a 4 years old file - this seems to be unrelated too.

Comment: I used this method to remove the MATE Desktop option from my Xfce installation.

Answer (score -1):

This is how it goes:

- Click on Settings manager at the app menu or run `xfce4-settings-manager` from a terminal
- Click on 'Session and Startup'
- Uncheck 'Display chooser on login' on the general tab, 'Session Chooser'
- Also review the 'Logout Settings' on the same tab.
- **In session tab, Click 'Clear saved session' **

Comment: I don't want to ignore all settings, but delete some of them.