# Xubuntu Applications Menu still shows deleted applications

Tags: xubuntu, appmenu

I originally installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a 64 bit PC, then installed the Xubuntu Desktop. I deleted some applications and eventually the Gnome Desktop. The Xubuntu Applications Menu still shows applications I've deleted. How can I get it to accurately display the Applications/Software on my computer?  I also still see the Gnome desktop as an option when I first log in. I'm confused and am very much a newbie to Linux, so please keep it simple. Thanks.

Comment: I installed the latest version of the Xubuntu Dessktop: 11.10

Answer (score 5):

menu entries can be removed from /usr/share/applications, so to remove them just
`sudo rm /usr/share/applications/appname.desktop`

also alacarte can be used
`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends alacarte` and then you can access via right click app menu - properties

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be the fix you're looking for, but if you right click on the base menu, and choose "Edit Menues" (or simply `<alt>`+`<f2>` and type "alacarte"), you can go in and manually add/remove menu entries.

Answer (score 0):

[Someone else](https://askubuntu.com/a/104541/43660) here has answered your apps menu question.  Luckily someone [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/81164/43660) has answered your 'how do I delete a login option' question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, folks. I've since re-installed 11.10 and moved on to 12.04. Things have gone much more smoothly since.

Comment: Did you try any of the proposed solutions?  If not, just make your own answer explaining what you did, and then mark it "solved" by clicking the checkmark to the left of your answer (I think you have to wait two days until you can accept your own answer).  It helps the site get just a tad cleaner.