# Remove Lubuntu entries from login screen

Tags: unity, xorg, lightdm, lubuntu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove session entries from LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

After I uninstalled the Lubuntu Desktop package (`lubuntu-desktop`), the lubuntu entries on the login screen are still present.

How can I remove them?