# Lightdm-too many desktop envirements

Tags: lightdm, desktop-environments

Today I tried to play with LXDE. After installing I go to login screen and try to select LXDE from list of avaible DE, but I can't select OK after that.
[image: screenshot]. I know this is bug, but maybe somebody can help me with finding temporary solution.
PS. This in in [Launchpad bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1071301), but it looks abbadoned.
PS2. Im am using Ubuntu 12.10, my screen is 1920x108.

Comment: This bug also affecting me even in Ubuntu 13.04... I have 15 Desktop Environments, and I have to use TAB button to switch between invisible Desktop Enviroment button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a workaround you can switch to lxdm, it includes a drop-down list that scrolls.

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

and select `lxdm` or another login manager like `gdm`

Restart the computer and you should be greeted with a different login manager.

---

If you *really need* to login to a different desktop, with lightdm in its current state (say the current selected one is unusable) you can use the <kbd>tab</kbd> key to cycle through the list, counting once the selection is off the screen until it cycles back to the top. You then know how many tabs it takes to get to the "OK" button, and can hit <kbd>enter</kbd> to select it.

---

Also it seems that the bug you linked is a duplicate of this bug, [Launchpad Bug 1068605](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1068605) be sure to click on the "This bug affects me"

---

And if there are some desktops you don't use: maybe a "2d" version of one desktop, or the openbox version of another... you can remove some from the list by following this question,
[How to remove session entries from LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

Or you may be able to change the LightDM greeter, [How to change the LightDM theme/greeter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75755/how-to-change-the-lightdm-theme-greeter)

Hopefully, that will give you some options to workaround the bug until it is fixed in future versions.