# KDE Won't Fully Remove

Tags: kde, purge

This is NOT a duplicate. The solution in [How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed) did NOT work, so please do not mark this as a duplicate (it ruined the last post I made). I am using Unity, but KDE is still available on the login screen. I have uninstalled it, and all of its programs, but it won't go away.

I did an installation of kde-full to try it, but I didn't like it and want to go back to just Unity.

Thanks in advance.

PS this installation is NOT Kubuntu.

UPDATE: KDE Plasma is still an option on the login screen, and choosing it opens a perfectly working KDE session. I have a 128GB SSD, so space is valuable.

UPDATE: KDevelop isn't that important. I don't have any custom configs, so if it gets deleted, I can reinstall it quickly.

Comment: Did you look in `/usr/share/xsessions/`? That's where the .desktop files for various logins are stored.

Comment: Aha! KDE is in there. It is a shortcut to /usr/bin/startkde. /usr/bin also has lots of other KDE files in it.

Comment: List of KDE files in /usr/bin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6736510/ (I installed KDevelop before KDE, I would like to keep that if possible.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I want to get rid of everything based on the `KDE` libraries (and, consequently, entirely remove `KDE`), I simply:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libkde*
```

(Before running the above command including the `--purge` option, make sure that you make a backup of the KDevelop config files.) If you want to keep KDevelop, as per your comment, then you can subsequently reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get install kdevelop
```

There may be KDE-related bits on the system (I'm not sure about this), but you definitely won't have any extraneous apps based on the KDE libraries (other than KDevelop and its deps).

Comment: Dupe? Look at the first answer. Basically says "remove libs, install KDevelop"

Comment: @pacificfils Not as far as I go. That answer talks in broad terms, while I give here exact instructions on how to definitively remove KDE (and reinstate a specific app if so desired).

Comment: @pacificfils Glad for this comment, as I wouldn't know how to specifically do that. Running now, will update with results.

Comment: It worked! KDE is no longer in the login menu, and I am now KDE free! I will award bounty in 1 hour, because it says I have to wait...?

Answer (score 4):

An KDE application you have still installed may depend on packages from the KDE environment. We can not remove all of KDE but keep single KDE applications.

In the case you mentioned in a comment it is expected to have **a lot** of KDE packages installed for being able to run KDevelop.

> You can't remove it's [dependencies](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/kdevelop) 
>   without removing kdevelop first.

In addition you may have other application still which may also depend on KDE libraries.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the answer you're looking for is in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81161/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm)

Basically it tells you that you find the sessions (i.e. the login entries) defined in

```
/usr/share/xsessions
```

Comment: That link removes a non-working DE. I can still choose it, log in, and get a perfectly working KDE desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, it is possible to run `sudo apt-get purge kubuntu-desktop` (note the purge) followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` (again, note the purge).

What this does is it removes `kubuntu-desktop` (which most if not all KDE packages depend on) and then purges all the files that depend/want `kubuntu-desktop` installed. This may remove kDevelop, however it is not hard to get back.

Comment: First command: not installed / not removed. Second command: removed some packages: "freespacenotifier* jovie* kdepasswd* kdm* kinfocenter* klipper* kmenuedit* libkprintutils4* libnepomukwidgets4* libokularcore3*"

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/pureubuntu

I hope it will help you, as it helped me.

Comment: Please expand the answer for it to be useful.

Comment: I get a few "not installed" messages and a few "unable to locate" messages.

Answer (score 0):

Since kubuntu and ubuntu share many packages, I suggest these commands...

```
sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```