# How to get back GNOME 2.x & GTK 2.x in 11.10?

Tags: gnome, gdm, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will I be able to run Gnome 2 in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54626/will-i-be-able-to-run-gnome-2-in-11-10)

I would like to get back my GNOME 2 desktop and GTK 2 and it's applications and also GDM instead of the new one. How is this achieved?