# How do I use LightDM with GNOME3?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, lightdm

I just installed GNOME3 following the steps from [another question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3/28392#28392)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

then installed [lightdm](https://launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/+archive/ppa), tried starting it and got a blank screen, what did I do wrong?

```
sudo apt-get install lightdm
sudo lightdm
```

then blank screen (is this normal?) ... restarted (using power button, is this blank screen normal?), selected Ubuntu GNOME Shell Desktop got "Failed to load sesson Gnome" tried Ubuntu and got "Failed to load session ubuntu" ...

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.04 Server on Virtual Box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

### This may not work for Installlation and you May Receive a Black Screen. Please Feel Comfortable with using the Recover Console and other methods before attempting to install,

---

**How to install**

Source is in Launchpad (bzr clone lp:lightdm) and tarball releases.
If you are using Ubuntu (Lucid or Maverick) you can install it from a PPA:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:robert-ancell/lightdm
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install lightdm lightdm-theme-webkit lightdm-theme-gnome
```

You can test lightdm by running it in a window:

```
 sudo apt-get install xserver-xephyr
```

Create the file lightdm.conf:

```
 [Greeter]
  theme=webkit
  lightdm –test-mode -c lightdm.conf
```

[image: LightDM]

[Install LightDM on Ubuntu](http://www.dreamingisdigital.com/2011/05/12/install-lightdm-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Where do I find/create lightdm.conf?

Comment: /etc/init/lightdm.conf

Comment: thanks, I also noticed the PPA I used is different `ppa:lightdm-team/ppa` from https://launchpad.net/~lightdm-team/+archive/ppa which should I use? I am on natty 11.04

Comment: or /etc/lightdm.conf seems to vary for some people.

Comment: the PPA you commented has version 0.3.3 the ppa form the article has version 0.3.2  i'd say use the newer one.

Comment: Hi again, sry but, the file has contents in it already, do I just append to it? ... I am still getting the same errors also I seem to be getting the default theme? not the one above in your answer

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/609983/ try with the contents in the link

Comment: though honestly seems to be very unstable right now, i would use SLIM instead seems to be easier to get it to work

Answer (score 1):

after installing I tried

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

**selected lightdm, rebooted and it is now working.**

Yes, it did show **blank black screen** while i was trying

```
sudo stop gdm
sudo start lightdm

sudo lightdm
```