# Is there an image of Ubuntu + Gnome3 available?

Tags: gnome, cd-image

Is this available somewhere. I want an image with nothing of unity in it only gnome 3. Something like the new Fedora. 
The problem is that when I tried gnome 3 in my current Ubuntu install the installation wasn't perfect. I just want to test a completely vanilla Ubuntu with gnome 3.

It is a pity for users like me that there was no image provided on the official website.

Will an image be provided? I don't dislike Unity but I was looking forward to try Gnome 3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no official image with GNOME 3/11.04 available, however GNOME3 is included in 11.10 and later.

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Have you given the following a try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

After issuing the above list commands in a terminal, restart the computer.  If you decide this is not doing what you want, you can remove everything installed here with the following command:

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Special Notes:

1. This is for Ubuntu 11.04
2. Ensure that you haven’t opened Ubuntu Software Center or Synaptic Package Manager while installing package from the command line.
3. **Installing Gnome 3.0 on Ubuntu 11.04 using this PPA, will break Unity and your system might become unusable.**

Comment: Then if I don't want to use Unity? Anyways, GNOME3 already provides functionality like Unity. Possible to disable Unity or something?

Comment: Something I was just contemplating, because I am not certain as how Unity may be eliminated completely, might an Ubuntu variation be appropriate?  That is, maybe one could start with Lubuntu (or some other flavor) and add Gnome 3 to it and not have to contend with Unity at all.

Comment: Tried this and was VERY unhappy about it. It installs a half broken gnome (when compared to the fedora version of gnome things just didn't look good). The problem is you feel right away its not vanilla.

Also when you return to unity you have to fix some stuff to get unity back to normal (at least I had to do it).

The question is really searching for a Vanilla install with gnome 3.

Answer (score 0):

When you first log on to your user account, after you click your name, there should be a little menu at the bottom that says something like "desktop:unity" you should be able to click in this box and change the default desktop to the Ubuntu classic or something, which may allow for an easier transition to Gnome 3.0 using [@Kory Wnuk's method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45494/is-there-an-image-of-ubuntu-gnome3-available/45510#45510) as posted.

Comment: (What the Heck!)I just posted here and it moved my post to the top, i edit it, now it's back at the bottom, ha! just follow Kory Wnuk's method after changing the default desktop type, wherever his method may appear on this thread!!