# Gnome3 on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, installation, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Hello i am trying to install gnome shell on Ubuntu 11.04 but i have some issues :

I followed this tutorial: http://techhamlet.com/2011/05/how-to-install-gnome-3-on-ubuntu-11-04/

But when install was completed , my system crashed and i could not log in . The effects was crashed and i formated my system :(

Can you help me please to install gnome 3?

Comment: There are several guides for this already on here http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3

Comment: If you have a specific issue that happens while you're installing Gnome3, you need to create a question that specifically address _this_ issue. Add lots of error messages and describe what you're doing exactly. In it's current form, "Can you help me please to install gnome 3?", it's an exact duplicate of the linked question. Hopefully, that one will solve your problem.