# How to enable File Manager to handle desktop after removing GNOME 3?

Tags: 11.04, unity, nautilus, gnome

I am student from Indonesia.

I've installed GNOME 3 from latest PPA and used instructions written by user Jon :

[How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

And after that, I removed GNOME 3 and used instructions from above question too. But in GNOME 3, right-click can't do in Desktop (File Manager does not handle desktop) and it's also exists to my old Unity desktop :(

How I can fix it?
Thanks so much.

---

Hmm, still not working :(
Thanks for the answer :D

By default in GNOME 3, File Manager does not handle the Desktop, but I using Gnome-Tweak-Tool for fix it... But before I removed GNOME 3, I return the initial setting 'File Manager does not Handle Desktop'
And the setting was also influential in Unity :(

Any others??

Answer (score 7):

Run following commands one-by-one from "Run" in Unity (using Alt+F2).

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background draw-background true`

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

If changes doesn't take place immediately, log-out and log-in again.