# My GNOME 3 looks different?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, wubi

I am a Ubuntu newbie. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.filiwiese.com/installing-gnome-on-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) to install Gnome 3 on my Ubuntu Precise Pangolin.

I was expecting a desktop like this:
[image: http://www.gnome.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/window-selection-3.12.png]
and I ended up with a desktop like this:
[image: http://imgur.com/dWIIkeI]
Please tell me what I can do to get the desired desktop.

NB: I have dual-booted using Wubi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like `GNOME Classic`. You should choose `GNOME` when selecting the session at login: (screenshot from the tutorial)
[image]

If you still get GNOME Classic, you can force GNOME Shell by running these commands in a terminal:

```
gnome-shell --replace &
disown
```

This will replace the current WM, send GNOME Shell to the background and detach it from the terminal so that you can close it without killing `gnome-shell`.

Comment: It **IS** Gnome. I didnt click on classic.

Comment: @LittleChild It certainly **looks** like GNOME Classic. Open a terminal and run `gnome-shell`.

Comment: `Window manager warning: Screen 0 on display ":0.0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.`

Comment: and not only that, my Gnome option has an Ubuntu symbol next to it rather than that footprint.

Comment: Ok, @LittleChild, so did you try the `replace` option? `gnome-shell --replace`?

Comment: Did a shell replace. Got the look. Shortcuts on the desktop stopped working plus I get an error http://pastebin.com/aqnPbHkE

Comment: @LittleChild wait a bit before accepting it. We need to make it permanent now. The odds are next time you log in, you will get GNOME Classic again.

Comment: The right click stops working in Gnome on desktop. Doesnt display any files and folders that were there on the desktop. I have to use the explorer.

Comment: @LittleChild try running the commands from [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/47262/158442) in a terminal.

Comment: done. That solves my desktop and right click problem. Now to make the shell permanent. How to? I get Classic every time I restart :)

Comment: @LittleChild I'll try if can get my hands on a 12.04 box (which might not be until Monday). You can perhaps edit your question to  reflect the fact that using the GNOME session gives you the GNOME Classic (or fallback) session, and the gnome-shell runs fine if you start it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the GNOME Shell you installed isn't compatible with your current Ubuntu version, so it fallbacks to the classic mode. GNOME Shell 3.4 is officially supported by Ubuntu Precise. Although it's a bit old, it's guaranteed to be stable and usable.

First of all, remove the PPA from Software Sources.

Then, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`

That should give you GNOME Shell 3.4. If you need 3.10 or above I think you should update your Ubuntu to 14.04.

Comment: How do i remove the PPA ?

Comment: @LittleChild: http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed

Comment: @muru so I should remove the `gnome-3` ppa ?

Comment: @LittleChild If the `--replace` succeeds, keep it. If not, we can try removing.

Comment: @muru I was following the steps here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277959/installing-gnome-3-8-on-ubuntu-12-04 look at answer number 2

Comment: @LittleChild between 3.6 and 3.10, GDM was a dependency of GNOME Shell, and it wouldn't even start without GDM. 3.4 was safe, I think.

Comment: @muru `Gnome 3.8 != kernel 3.8` what does this mean? :)

Comment: @LittleChild that the kernel and Gnome are different projects with unrelated version numbers. They both had version 3.8 at some time, but that was coincidence.

Comment: @muru The latest version of Ubuntu has Gnome by default, right ?

Comment: @LittleChild No, Ubuntu still uses Unity by default. You can try Ubuntu Gnome Edition if you want Gnome by default: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/14.04/release/

Comment: @muru I should go for `PC (Intel x86) desktop image`? I have i3 processor :)

Comment: @LittleChild you can use the `amd64` image. The i3 is 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first screenshot is what you get if you press the Super key, not the desktop. But it's been a while since I used Ubuntu Gnome.

Comment: Tried that also. Didnt work.