# How do I install Gnome 3 on 10.10?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME Shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)

I tried to find out how to install Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 10.10, but all I found is GnomeShell.

Is it possible anyway to install Gnome 3?