# Failed to install GNOME3 with 404 error

Tags: 11.04, gnome

I followed the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3), however I got 404 not found error checking for updates:

`W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugnometeam/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found, 
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugnometeam/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found, 
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
,

Thus I couldn't even start the installation. Anybody know how to perform a full installation?

Now got new error:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/i18n/Translation-en  Connection failed, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And these are all the files in *sources.list.d*:

```
gnome3-team-gnome3-natty.list
gnome3-team-gnome3-natty.list.save
mozillateam-firefox-stable-maverick.list
mozillateam-firefox-stable-maverick.list.distUpgrade
mozillateam-firefox-stable-maverick.list.save
pidgin-ppa.list
pidgin-ppa.list.distUpgrade
pidgin-ppa.list.save
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have added the wrong PPA, [the instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3) state that the PPA is `ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`, the PPA you're getting errors for is some other PPA run by someone else.

You can remove bad sources by following the instructions here:

- [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)

From your file list I see that you have `gnome3-team-gnome3-natty.list`, this is where the bad URL is. You'll want to remove that file and then follow the linked directions for the right instructions to add the PPA.

Comment: I'm sure that I added ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 and the URLs in the software sources are same as those in the instruction, quite strange

Comment: Did you add those also on top of adding the other ones? That would also cause the error.

Comment: What do you mean by _those also on top of adding the other ones_?

Comment: I tried the Command line Instructions and the first 2 lines worked fine, but when doing the dist-upgrade, the download speed was really really slow... less than 1kb/s...

Comment: @littne Please post the contents of the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ in your question so we can see the files.

Comment: Actually you've solved my problem about the 404 error, thanks for your patience.