# How to install Gnome3 in future versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

In Natty you can install Gnome 3 via a PPA.

For future versions such as Ubuntu 11.10, how would I install Gnome 3?

Answer (score 5):

"Gnome 3" is often confused with "gnome-shell".

Trying to simplify, [Gnome 3](http://www.gnome.org/gnome-3/) is basically the

- Graphical User Interface (GUI) called gnome-shell
- a number of [key applications](http://www.gnome.org/applications/) and
- an extensive set of underlying libraries of code for the above.

Future versions of Ubuntu will use many of the key applications and the vast majority of underlying libraries of code. The remaining "Gnome 3" applications from above can be installed via Software Center.

Thus, this just leaves the GUI from the list above.  From Ubuntu 11.10 onwards, the default GUIs available will be Unity-3D and Unity-2D.  Assuming you need the GUI "gnome-shell", this is available to be installed through the Repositories as well.

There is a package in Software Center (or synaptic manager - if installed) called `gnome-shell`.

Install that and it will be available in your sessions menu to be selected when you next logon.

At the time of writing, 11.10 (oneiric) is in alpha.  A [number of issues](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1803777) relating to integrating gnome-shell exists.  You should consult this [AU Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18641/theres-an-issue-with-an-alpha-release-of-ubuntu-what-should-i-do) before posting further more specific questions about Oneiric.

Comment: gnome shell is not gnome 3 - he probably asks for gnome 3 itself not one of its shells

Comment: Really? I bet he asks for GNOME Shell, not for GNOME 3. :P

Comment: Isn't Gnome 3 used by default in 11.10?

Comment: Ya. GNOME 3 is used in 11.10. GNOME Shell is not the same as GNOME 3.

Comment: @ fossfreedom and others

many thanks for the replies. And yes, since it's Ubuntu 11.10 we are talking about, I *did* assume Gnome=Gnome3.

Anyway I installed gnome-shell and after reboot when I tried to log into Gnome, I'm getting  this "Failed to load session "gnome"" error but since these are nightly/daily builds I think it's kinda normal so will try again after few weeks.

Comment: yes - here to - it was working a couple of weeks ago.  Looks like it is broken again.  I expect it will be fixed in a week or so.