# Fix Unity after uninstalling Gnome 3

Tags: unity, gnome

Well, I installed and uninstalled Gnome 3 as indicated on this answer: [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3/28392#28392)

I have, however, noticed that the dash now keeps being in it's default configuration, and it has some minor bugs.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: The linked answer does state this: "**reverting back to vanilla 11.04 is not trivial.**" Be prepared for a lot of work, if it's even possible to fully restore everything to working order. You may just be better off reinstalling your OS.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought about. But I still want to keep all my files (can do it) and the conf files (not sure how to do it)

Comment: Indeed you're better off re installing Ubuntu, your conf files ar stored on your home in hidden directories, and if you have your home on a separate partition you can just re install Ubuntu and everything will be as it was before.

Comment: ok, so I finally have an excuse not to delay moving /home to a separate partition. If you write this as a proper answer I'd be glad to mark it as the good one

Answer (score 2):

*OP solved issue by comment here*

ok, so I finally have an excuse not to delay moving /home to a separate partition. If you write this as a proper answer I'd be glad to mark it as the good one – gumbo Sep 3 '11 at 22:01