# How to install Gnome-Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

What is the easiest way to install Gnome 3 and Gnome-Shell in Beta 1 of 11.10?  Also is it worth doing and is it stable enough to do so?