# Installed GNOME 3 and the default theme looks horrible, how can I change?

Tags: gnome

I just [installed gnome 3 as in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3) on a freshly installed 11.04 system. I don't want to play with themes, but I'm just looking for something decent. The default one is quite dull. I was using Ubuntu 10.04 and the default was fine for me. How can I change to some other theme?

[image: desktop screenshot]

After removing gnome-accessibility-themes, it looks worse:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with the accessibility themes in Gnome Shell. You can fix it by running

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-accessibility-themes
sudo apt-get install gnome-themes-standard
```

then logging out and back in again.

Comment: check edit... this one sucks more..

Comment: Hmm, you may have to reboot instead of just log out. I had this issue and those commands fixed it. [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1742343) talks about some Gnome Shell upgrade issues and this theme issue is one of them. The thread does say to reboot though, not just log out.