# Gnome issues after downgrading from Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, package-management, gtk, downgrade

I followed this [post on AU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3/28392#28392) and then downgraded back to 2.32. Then I followed a tip in a post asking me to add the gnome3 PPA to install a package  `dconf-settings-backend` because my settings weren't being remembered even after installing `dconf-tools` and `libdconf0`. Now I have the following issues:

- The time it takes from gdm login for the desktop-background to paint and the notification area icons to appear and conky to load has gotten high which wasn't the case earlier.
- Although I am connected to a network and can browse the internet, there is no network icon in my notification area.
- Although there are files in my Desktop folder, I am unable to see them except for `ls` via terminal
- The buttons to close, minimize and maximize have disappeared from all windows.
- Nautilus doesn't open. When I try to open nautilus via the terminal I encounter this error:

> ```
> nits@nits-workstation:~$ nautilus .
>
> Gtk-ERROR **: GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3
> in the same process is not supported
> aborting...
> Aborted
> ```

I am guessing there is a package confusion with the upgrade from and downgrade back to Gnome2. Please help me fix this. Thanks.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: @poolie: Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like quite a mess.  Perhaps you should just reinstall.

But there are some other things you can try:

- `/var/log/dpkg.log` tells you which packages were installed recently; perhaps you can use that to undo some actions.
- I would certainly start by removing any relevant PPAs and packages installed from them.
- `dpkg -l libgtk\*` will tell you which 3.0 libraries are installed; possibly by pulling out `libgtk-3-0` and related things you can force removal of "gnome 3".
- `strace -e trace=open nautilus` will show you which libraries it's using and that might give you a clue as to which package is causing the problem.
- Running `synaptic` and looking at the local/obsolete section might help you find packages that aren't in your base OS and ought to be removed.

Comment: Awesome!!! I removed the PPA, and searched for libgtk-3.0* packages. Removed the packages that were dependant on them and then removed them itself. Now I am back to my sweet unity desk! Thanks a mil!

Comment: No problem, I am glad (and a bit surprised) I could help.