# Can I choose between GNOME Shell and Unity on login?

Tags: unity, gnome

After installing the `gnome-shell` package, will I have option to switch between Unity 3D and `gnome-shell` at the time of logging in (just like we have choice for unity 3d and 2d)?

Comment: Hum, 11.10 already includes GNOME3 - oh, you must be talking about GNOME Shell...

Answer (score 9):

Install the package [gnome-shell](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell), then you get an additional session `GNOME` in the login screen:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Comment: You will also want to install the package <a href="apt:gnome-tweak-tool">gnome-tweak-tool</a>. After installing gnome-shell (more precisely, gnome-themes-standard, which comes with it), you will be able to select the Adwaita theme for windows and GTK+, and the Gnome theme for icons. I really recommend doing this, because Gnome Shell has been crafted very carefully around those themes :)