# In 11.10 how do I swich between Unity and Gnome Shell sessions?

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Is there an easy way to switch between Unity and Gnome Shell and back whenever I want to change my desktop sessions?

Comment: See update below

Comment: Oh due to a lot of gnome updates when I first installed oneiiric I assumed it was already installed. Must be that unity has a lot of gnome dependancies as is.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have both installed, you can choose which session you want at the login manager (login screen).