# Installing gnome shell as separate session

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

I would like to install Gnome-shell as a separate session because I don't want to mess with my current desktop settings, etc. (I have did huge customisations). How to do that? Any tutorial available? Btw, I use Linux mint katya as my main Desktop.

Comment: Voting to close - [Linux Mint is off-topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/684/linux-mint-and-other-unofficial-derivatives-on-topic)

Comment: Besides being off-topic - this topic in general has already been covered.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 11.10, you can click this link: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell.

Comment: But we ARE in 11.04 so why tell us what we can do in half a year?

Comment: By my calendar, October 13th is in two weeks, not six months.

Comment: Still you live in a world that doesn't exist so why do you answer something that he/she/it doesn't ask for?

Comment: Because the alternative would be to say "Linux Mint is not Ubuntu and we don't support it". I prefer to argue for the things I like rather than against the things I don't.

Comment: The link is software. Including it here would mean thousands of lines of code. :)

Comment: @StephenMyall That canned comment is not appropriate for all posts that are short and contain a link. It's important to look at the context to see if it really makes sense for information from the linked page to be added to the post.