# Will Gnome 3 be in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I want to ask in the upcoming release of Ubuntu 11.10, are they giving Gnome 3?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 11.10 includes GNOME 3 GTK+3 libraries with the updated Unity user interface.

If you want, you can install GNOME Shell using these directions:

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Comment: Thanks for reply. So you are saying when I will update my 11.04 to 11.10. I will get Gnome 3 with Unity interface. Or I need to explicitly get by installing gnome-shell?

Comment: @Tahir - no - you will need to explicitly install gnome-shell.  It will appear as "Gnome" in your sessions list.

Comment: Tahir: GNOME = application (nautilus, totem, file-roller...) + libraries (gtk..) + tools (gvfs, gconf/gsettings...) + user interface (GNOME Shell); in Ubuntu 11.10 you have GNOME with Unity instead of GNOME Shell (and some GNOME apps are replaced), so you have to install just GNOME Shell.