# Will the new version be using the improved unity shell or gnome3? 

Tags: unity, 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Will Gnome 3 be in 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64200/will-gnome-3-be-in-11-10)

Will the new version be using the improved unity shell or gnome3? If it's using unity, can I still install gnome3 on it???

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 11.10 will be using Unity, which now works with Gnome 3. Gnome Shell, which is the "default shell of Gnome 3" will also be available. In other words, Gnome 3 can be styled in various ways. Gnome-Shell is the default of the Gnome Developers, while Ubuntu chooses to use the Unity Shell by default.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu 11.10 will be similar to Ubuntu 11.04, only with some slight modifications.

Gnome <strike>shell</strike> Dektop will not be available in 11.10 as was there in 11.04 as a roll back feature. Instead they are planning to ship a 2D version of Unity for slower graphics cards, instead of a 3D one.

And Pitivi is not being a part of the distro CD. anyway Pitivi was useless for me!

Reference: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29)

Comment: Gnome Shell is available in 11.10. It was not available in 11.04 because of the very limited time. Why are you talking about pitivi?

Comment: @^ please refer to the wiki site I have included before commenting anything....

Comment: You make absolutely no sense. :|

Comment: @^..and why's that???

Comment: PiTiVi is a video editor. Gnome Shell and Unity are shells for the Gnome 3 Desktop Environment. Why are you talking about video editing? And why do you say that the Gnome desktop won't be available? The gnome desktop is default in Ubuntu.

Comment: I discussed Pitivi just as an additional information i.e its not be der in 11.10. And again gnome desktop is not available...see the link i have provided...and check for what shuttleworth has said..Correct me if im wrong....

Comment: The Gnome desktop is installed by default, using the Unity shell. Gnome Shell is available too, but it needs to be installed.

Comment: precisely, that's what i said...it need to be installed from repo...it will not be shipped with the distro cd...