# Start Ubuntu directly into GNOME 3 interface rather than Unity

Tags: unity, 11.10, updates, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and had many issue and that's OK because it is still in beta version and i installed GNOME 3 and in love with it and want my system to startup directly into GNOME interface, so in case thats possible please help me out