# How to delete gnome 3.4 themes in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I want to see if I can delete all themes and fix the Notification I have.  I have deleted the PPA's, but the themes are still in Gnome Tweak. Where are themes located so I can remove them?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes can be in two folders depending on how you installed them

First it is here

> /usr/share/themes

Second is here

> .Themes

Which is located in your Home file , please click Ctrl+H or Show Hidden Folders from View Menu.

But please take a caution while deleting the Default Installed themes Packed by
Ubuntu.

Comment: I do appreciate the input by all.  The themes installed by PPA were removed and a different theme was installed after reboot (not by PPA).  Same issue, notifications do no work. I suspect a bug in Gnome 3.4, but what do I know.

Comment: In Synaptic , search for notification-daemon , check if it is installed or not.

Comment: It was not.  Installed and did a reboot. Still no Notifications except with the default theme.  Thanks for the tip, I just have a feeling this is a simple fix.

Comment: I don't know if it is set to auto start or not.
Try this in terminal 

 cd /etc/xdg/autostart/

sudo sed --in-place 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' *.desktop


Then open Startup Applications for the menu , if notifications are  present there Check Mark to autostart it .

Comment: Did as you said but Notifications was not present.

Comment: What if Gnome was removed, completely (purge?) and then installed fresh?  Just a thought.  Unity is working flawlessly, which surprises me as I never liked it.

Comment: Well you gotta try that.

Comment: I assume the command is sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell-*.  Will that delete Gnome Tweak and all folders?

Comment: You should refer this http://askubuntu.com/questions/65200/remove-gnome-shell-completely-after-installing-it

Answer (score 3):

Themes are normally located at:

If installed via PPA:

```
/usr/share/themes/
```

If installed locally:

```
~/.themes/
```

---

Removing themes:

PPA ones:

```
sudo apt-get remove <theme_package_name>
```

Local ones:

```
rm -rf ~/.themes/*
```

Don't forget to set your GTK theme to the default first, otherwise your current session might go nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

They should be in **/usr/share/themes**, but if you installed them via ppa you shouldn't just remove the Folders but remove the packages with Software Center or apt-get!

Comment: I would like to remove the original Ubuntu themes and add custom themes ? 
Will removing "ubuntu-artwork" from the software center removes the original themes ? 
And, how to load the other installed themes in the thee section of appearance window in Ubuntu12.04 ?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend to remove the original themes, why do you want to remove them?
You can install them by downloading them as archive (should be one Folder inside for every theme) and putting the Folder(s) inside to either **.themes** in your home directory or to **/usr/share/themes**. You can also install them with your package manager, I don't know if there are any in the official repositories but webupd8 has a ppa with many themes: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/themes