# How to remove Ubuntu-Gnome extra shells

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome

Had new installation of Ubuntu-Gnome then add Unity via:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now I have all this shells at log-in screen

- System Default
- Gnome
- Gnome Classic
- Ubuntu

I am trying to tune this OS while keeping one Unity and one Gnome:

```
$ uname -a
3.16.0-31-generic #41~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 11 19:30:13 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.10.4
```

What is the best way to do that?  i.e purge the two extra shells.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the default session for when using auto-logins?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62833/how-do-i-change-the-default-session-for-when-using-auto-logins)

Comment: Am trying to purge the two extra shell without harming the OS

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make that clear in the title and the text...

Answer (score 1):

`System Default` is just an alias for the system default (i.e., if you didn't change your configuration, `GNOME Classic`), and I believe it cannot be removed from the list. To remove `GNOME Classic`:

```
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session-fallback
```

And to remove its entry from the sessions entries:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/xsessions/gnome-classic.desktop
```

Comment: Used the one-liner provided at (http://askubuntu.com/questions/65200/remove-gnome-shell-completely-after-installing-it) It did not delete Gnome Classic, although, it changed it a little "like top-middle search disappeared " Then running your command yield ( Package 'gnome-session-fallback' is not installed, so not removed )

Comment: @user176105 Do you mean this command? `sudo apt-get purge alacarte cups-pk-helper gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-fallback indicator-applet-complete libpanel-applet-4-0 python-gmenu`, if yes than `gnome-session-fallback` has been removed already, that's why it won't remove it again. To remove the entry from the sessions entries look at the updated answer

Comment: Yes this is the command I used ( sudo apt-get purge alacarte cups-pk-helper gir1.2-gconf-2.0 gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0 gnome-applets gnome-applets-data gnome-panel gnome-panel-data gnome-session-fallback indicator-applet-complete libpanel-applet-4-0 python-gmenu ) It does not look like an entry-- it would give me no data source upon login as with other Ubuntu releases.

Comment: @user176105 Sorry but i can't understand what you're describing, can you post a screenshot? Or rephrase it differently?

Comment: Currently: $ cd /usr/share/xsessions:/usr/share/xsessions          $ ls
gnome-classic.desktop  gnome.desktop  ubuntu.desktop

Comment: it looks like this (http://ubuntu.aspcode.net/view/635400140124705175137036/how-to-remove-session-entries-from-lightdm) May be my answer.

Comment: @user176105 Ok, so you still have the entry, have you tried the second command in my anser? Try it and reboot, and see if the entry is removed.