# How to install missing GNOME3/ GNOME Shell applications (Documents, Web apps, Sushi, etc.)?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

I waited to install gnome 3, shell etc on Ubuntu, using it on Debian and Fedora in the meantime, because it was "going to be straightforward" on Oneiric.

Now I find that the repos only contain part of the full Gnome 3 environment, some packages are out of date, and the bits that do exist have often been hacked in order to make them work with Unity.

As a test, I installed the whole system from the upstream source code on a test machine. Works great, but just like 11.04, Unity no longer works.

Is it ever going to be possible to have a full Gnome 3 experience on Ubuntu or will it always be made to suck in order to avoid comparison with Unity?

Comment: @Duncan Just to clarify (because I'm doubting this is a duplicate, just poorly worded), are you asking how to install GNOME Shell, or are you asking how to get Documents / Contacts / Sushi previews / all that stuff up and running? If so, [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/) has a number of articles and PPAs available that restore some of this missing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that its a comparison issue, never was, never will be.

You are complaining about outdated packages on a release that is beta atm, beta means not ready for general public, there are issues, use it at your own risk. Nothing else to say here I think.

Answer (score 0):

Which question do you want answered? If it is the question in the title, then see the answer to this previous question:

[See the answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

If you want either of the two questions in the last sentence answered, then, I can only express an opinion. This kind of question cannot be given a definitive answer. I suspect that you are not asking a question at all but moaning.

Regards.