# Can I have Gnome-shell and Unity together?

Tags: unity, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Can I have Gnome-shell and Unity available in ubuntu? I mean can I switch between Gnome-shell and unity at the login session?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here. This may be due to terminology mixup. Gnome3 is the default Desktop Environment in 11.10 - Unity will be the default Shell. If you're asking if you can use Gnome Shell and Unity on the same installation then please update your question.

Comment: It seems like he/she is asking if it is possible to use GNOME Classic, or GNOME Shell - but is rather hard to tell.

Comment: Its Gnome Shell since what most people call Gnome Classic is the 2.x versions of Gnome and what most call Gnome 3.x is the Gnome Shell

Comment: I'm sorry about that confusing question.. I still confuse between gnome-shell and gnome 3.2..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: YES but in Ubuntu 11.10 and up which will come in 1 or 2 days. It will come with unity and you can install via the **Software Center** the package `gnome-shell` (Which some wrongly call gnome3 or gnome3.2). After installing it just logout and you should see in the login both of them (unity and gnome-shell)

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait a couple days, this will be a whole lot easier after you upgrade to 11.10.  Just search for and install "gnome-shell" in the software centre.