# Can't Install "Gnome Shell" 

Tags: gnome, software-installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME 3?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

When I try to install Gnome Shell by pressing:

> apt://gnome-shell,gnome-themes-standard

the Software Center opens and says:

> **Not found**
>   There isn't a software package called "gnome-shell,gnome-themes-standard" in your current software sources.

I tried to switch between "Main Server", "Server for United States" and "Server for Lithuania" (my country) it didn't work.

I also checked **"main"**, **"universe"**, **"restricted"** and **"multiverse"** didn't work either.

BTW I'm using an upgraded version from Ubuntu 11.04 not a fresh install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* no package called "gnome-shell,gnome-shell-themes-standard". However, there is a package called gnome-shell, and there is a package called gnome-shell-themes-standard. You just can't ask for both in a url.

You can install Gnome Shell from here: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gnome-shell/

- [How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-3)

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

then choose Gnome from start menu at login [Gnome SHell](http://cdn.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/shell-log-500x290.jpg)