# GNOME Shell interface not working anymore after NVIDIA X Server settings changes

Tags: 11.10, nvidia, gnome

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 two days ago and at the same time installed gnome-shell (Unity just doesn't feel right for me).

Everything was working fine until this morning, when logging in my session I found that the interface of gnome shell just wasn't here anymore. I can see my desktop, but instead of the usual notification bar on the top of the screen I only have the equivalent of the right-click menu on the desktop.

The key "Super" doesn't do anything and actually nothing works properly.

I don't know if this is related (Must be) but I did some changes in the NVidia XServer settings. But I did a backup of the xorg.conf file, and even reverting to it doesn't solve my problems...

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have the Alternate Status Menu extension installed?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what changes you made to your settings?

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11586016#post11586016

Answer (score 1):

try to look at the problem easier )

Perhaps, just together with updating Xorg was changed default shell setting. If you install full GNOME3 pack then you should to have option in your Greeter(or standart Gnome Login) the menu for choosing shell.

GNOME3 include 3 'features':

- Gnome
- Gnome Classic
- Gnome Classic (without effects)

Or if this solution is not figure out of problem then post some screens.

Also I suppose so that maybe problem of using LightDM instead GDM.
To fix use solution from:
[GDM killed on startup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77652/gdm-killed-on-startup/90701#90701)

Also very recommended to reading and bookmarking:
[How do I install and use the latest version of GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome-shell)