# GDM killed on startup

Tags: 11.10, boot, gdm, upstart

In order to fix a sound issue, I'd completely removed all PulseAudio packages, which removed several additional packages which I hadn't kept track of.

I have since added back several packages that had depended upon some of the packages, such as xubuntu-desktop (yes, I'm using Xubuntu, not the default Ubuntu setup).

Unfortunately, this has broken my setup a little bit, in that on boot, my graphical desktop manager is not started automatically. (in this case, I'm using GDM, not LightDM)

I can switch to a virtual terminal (via Alt-F1), login, then launch GDM with the following command:

```
sudo service gdm start
```

But this doesn't solve the problem itself.

I've also discovered that GDM *is* being started upon boot, but it's also getting killed by something.

Any help you guys can give would be great, because this is getting beyond annoying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

```
sudo apt-get install -f -m --reinstall -u gdm
```

---

*Meaning of the short options:*

> `-f` *: fix broken*
>
> `-m` *: fix missing*
>
> `--reinstall` *: refresh archives to newest versions*

*Useful option:*

> `-u` *: print out a list of all packages that are to be upgraded*

---

**Next:**

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

`▶` `select GDM instead LightDM`

**Finally:**

```
sudo reboot
```

Enjoy!